# Building and publishing an npm package with a JavaScript namespace object

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I published an npm package. The directory structure is something like the following:

```
elephant-lib-test
└── js/script.js
└── index.js
└── package.json
```

The `js/script.js` file contains a JavaScript namespace object:

```
var elephant = {
    printElephant: function() {
        console.log("Elephant");
    },
    doSomething: function() {
        console.log("Do something");
    }
}
```

In my `index.js` file, I am exporting this like so:

```
import { elephant } from "./js/script.js";

export default elephant;
```

After publishing, I installed the npm package and tried to use it using the following code:

```
const elephant = require("elephant-lib-test");
console.log(elephant);
elephant.printElephant();
elephant.doSomething();
```

The first two lines work, and the second line returns this in my console:

```
Module {default: undefined, __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}
```

However, the third line causes an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: elephant.printElephant is not a function
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I am sorry if this is really obvious, but I am just starting out with npm, so I would really appreciate an answer with a tiny bit of explanation along with code. You can find the actual package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/elephant-lib-test

Thanks for any help.

**Edit** I have added `export { elephant };` to end of the `js/script.js` file, but still get the same error.

Comment: How are you `export`'ing `elephant`from within the  `js/script.js` file?

Comment: I am not. This is the part where I am struggling.

Comment: Then add `export { elephant };` at the bottom of your `js/script.js`. Btw. ECMAScript modules are still _[Experimental](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules)_ -  you may want to consider continuing with the [CommonJS.](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules) module format for a while yet.

Comment: @RobC I added `export { elephant };` to the end of the JS file, but still get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: elephant.printElephant is not a function`

Comment: Also [enable ESM modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_enabling) by either: **A)** Adding `"type": "module"` to _package.json_.  Or **B)** Change your file extensions from `.js` to `.mjs`. _Note: In your example code shown whereby you try to use the package, you may also need to change `const elephant = require("elephant-lib-test");` to `import elephant from "elephant-lib-test";`